# Not able to see the thumbnail for my extensions in "chrome://settings/extensions" when I load a unpacked extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, icons

I am loading an unpacked extension but I am unable to see any thumbnails for my extension under chrome://settings/extensions?

Whether I should add anything in manifest file?

Here is my manifest file..

```
{
   "name": "a1",
   "version": "1.0",
   "description": "a1",
   "background_page": "background.html",
   "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "icon.png",
     "popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension - Image of Extension on Settings Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097906/chrome-extension-image-of-extension-on-settings-page)

Answer (score 3):

`browser_action.default_icon` is only the icon for the button next to the omnibar. If you want an icon in `chrome://settings/extensions` you need to set the [icon](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#icons) value.

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't appear to work. Instead of the icon in the chrome://chrome/extensions/ panel I get a jigsaw puzzle icon. I've defined 16, 48 and 128 icons.

Comment: Strange. I renamed the directory and re-added the extension, then it worked. Perhaps something was being cached.

Comment: Renaming the directory did not work for me - nor do these manifest file settings