# Chrome Extension - Image of Extension on Settings Page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, icons

I am trying to figure out how to get an image/icon of our extension to display on the Settings->Extensions page. I looked through the manifest api but the closest thing I found related to this was to include "Icons" which did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at my manifest (where I have an icon) I have:

```
{
   "name": "Obviously there's more to my manifest file. Also, I'm not using manifest version 2 yet", 
   "icons":
   {
      "128": "images/icon128.png",
      "16": "images/icon16.png",
      "48": "images/icon48.png"
   }
}
```

Comment: always try reloading the extension, even restart chrome

Comment: Yup. Seems like I had to remove the extension, exit Chrome, then install it for the Icons to appear.

Comment: `Ctrl + F5` on the settings page causes the icons to be reloaded as well. There's no need to restart the browser.

Comment: @NewAlexandria You have to reload your extension, close `chrome://extensions`, then open it again.

Comment: And be sure you haven't interchanged the contents of `icons` and `default_icon`. I spent over 10 minutes debugging the same error I made. Your `manifest.json` should look something like `{ "action": { "default_icon": { }}, "icons": {}}`