# Why doesn't extension management icon for my Chrome extension show?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, icons

I am trying to add an icon that displays next to the name of my Chrome extension in the extensions panel. I have tried using the following manifest.json file.

```
{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": { "16": "mediumIcon.png", "48": "mediumIcon.png", "128": "mediumIcon.png" },
  "description": "A practice extension.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "smallIcon.png",
    "default_popup": "load.html"
  }
}
```

mediumIcon.png is 128x128. When I enter developer mode in the Extensions tab in Chrome and load my unpacked extension, the icon is not next to the name of my extension. Actually, a black-and-white version of the icon flashes for a split second, after which the default Chrome extension icon (that looks like a puzzle piece) appears.

Why not? I thought that the documentation noted that the icons can scale down if necessary.

Comment: Close the `chrome://extensions/` tab, and open it again. Does it solve the problem? Can you include the image (host on imgur)?

Comment: Hmm, refreshing didn't, but restarting the browser did. Thanks!

Comment: I specifically said closing and re-opening. I've experienced this before, and refreshing didn't help indeed. You're welcome ;)

Comment: restarting my browser did not make the difference (Chrome 31)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension - Image of Extension on Settings Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097906/chrome-extension-image-of-extension-on-settings-page)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [documentation for icons](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#icons) in chrome extension states two things that relate to your problem:

> Important: Use only the documented icon sizes.

and

> provide a 48x48 icon, which is used in the extensions management page

If you provide icon of different size where 48x48 should have been used, it will be ignored. Since the icon on the management page is generated from the 48x48 version, it will not be displayed.

The solution for your problem is to provide image with correct dimensions for each icon definition.

Answer (score 5):

```
{
  "name": "Chrome Extention",
  "page_action": {
    },
  "icons": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    }
}
```

Remove `icons` attribute from `page_action` and put it at the root level.